# Is there a way to reduce the memory use of this queue?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, queue

In liberal C:

```
/* i'm using this */

struct QueueItem
    {
    QueueItem* next;
    void* data;
    }

struct Queue
    {
    QueueItem* head;
    QueueItem* tail;
    }

/*
    +---+    +---+
    |0 0|    |* *|  len 1
    +---+    +|-|+
              v v
     len     +---+
      0      |d 0|
             +---+
    
    +---+
    |* *---------...---+
    +|--+              |  len n
     v                 v
    +---+  +---+      +---+
    |a *-->|b *--...->|z 0|
    +---+  +---+      +---+
*/
```

This gives O(1) for all push/pop/peek and O(n) traversal, but uses 2+2n memory.
A naive array version give a minimum of 2+n (about optimal), but is usually
worse, and sometimes causes modifications to take longer (for reallocation).

```
struct Queue
    {
    size_t len;
    size_t head;
    void (*data)[];
    }

/*
    +-----+
    |* * *-----~~~-+
    +|-|--+        |
     v +-+         |
    +----v-----~~~-v+
    |0 0 a b c . . z|
    +----------~~~--+
*/
```

It looks like there is no way to improve memory usage with sacrificing preformance, but i wanted to at least put this out there in case anyone knows a way around this.

#### Edit (because i cant have code in comments):

```
struct QueueItem
{
    QueueItem* next;
    size_t len;
    void (*data)[];
    }

struct Queue
    {
    QueueItem* head;
    QueueItem* tail;
    size_t start;
    size_t end; //edit: need to know where to push data. edit: not per-item
    }

/*
    +-----+
    |* * *------------------------------+
    +|-|--+                             |
     v +---+        (2x longer)         v (much longer)
    +------v----+  +-----------+       +---------------+
    |@ 0 0 a b *-->|@ c . . h *-->...->|@ . . . x y z 0|
    +-----------+  +-----------+       +---------------+
*/
```

Comment: Hmm.  In your current solution, you show each new QueueItem with an array 2x longer than the last.  I don't think this is a good idea if you are popping items off the queue.  Now the longer your queue lives, the more wasted space you will have, independent of how large the queue is at any moment.

Comment: @cape1232, yeah, i'm still on "make it work" for the new structure; i'll add size capping later.

Comment: @$re: size capping, how about initial size = 1 and no `chunklen*=2` if `q->head->next == q->tail` (ie: if `nchunks(q) == 2`) that way chunksize still grows quickly as items are added (reducing overhead by a factor of 2 with each new chunk), but stablizes between len/3 and len/2 when you start consuming items. When items are consumed rapidly enough to keep the queue depleted, it alternates between 4 and 7 pointer widths, which is fine if there are a fixed number of queues and not too bad if there are more (in which case large memory use is likely to happen anyway).

Comment: what exact operations shall the queue offer?

Comment: @Dave, the main ones are `push` (add a item to the end of the queue), `pop` (remove and return a item from the front of the queue), and `peek` (like pop, but dont remove the item); i also added `prepend` (add an item to front of queue), since it is trivial to add and might be useful. All of these operations are effectively O(1), though memory allocation may interfere with push or prepend (or fail). Theres also `traverse` (callback on each queued item) which is neccesarily O(n).

Comment: I think `chunklen` needs to also be able to decrease, or else your queue will have size proportional to its largest-ever size even if it is empty.  So how about `if (q->head->next == q->tail) chunklen/=2`?

Comment: @cape1232, size decrease is probably needed, but i am not sure `q.h.n == q.t` is the way to go; eg: loop{push();push();pop();} gives no more than 1/2 spaces used, and as little as 1/3. I'm too tired to figure out whether thats a corner case or not, so it worrys me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you neglect the cost of allocating the QueueItems.  So the allocation costs between your two approaches is the same.  (Someone more knowledgeable about memory allocation, please speak up if I'm wrong.)

You can do this to alleviate the wasted space for popped/unfilled items in the array.  Make a hybrid of the list and array.  Let each list node contain an array of size K.

```
struct QueueItem
    {
    QueueItem* next;
    void (*data)[K];
    }

struct Queue
    {
    QueueItem* head;
    QueueItem* tail;
    size_t head;
    size_t end;
    }
```

Now your performance is dictated by the size you choose for the array.  The smaller it is, the less wasted space you have.  The larger it is, the less your QueueItem overhead costs you as a percentage of overall space.  If you knew, say, that your queue will usually be of size N, then you might choose K to be N/10.  In that case, the total memory cost is N/K + 4 + N.  The maximum amount of space you can waste in the arrays on unused elements is 2*K - 2.

Usage patterns will dictate actual performance.  But if you can anticipate your usage pattern, you can choose a K that works well.  There might even be a way to adaptively choose K differently for each node to get even better performance, but I think that's beyond me right now.

Comment: Also, `item->head` doesnt have to be per-item, since all but `q->head` should be full.

Comment: @David X  Sorry about the comment desync.  Probably because I deleted my first answer.

Comment: @David X re: `item->head`: nice.  As per your edit, we also need an `end`.  I'll edit.

Comment: @$re:end, which doesn't need to be per-item either now i have to fix my answer edit again.

Comment: Hah, I should have waited for one more upvote before deleting my first answer.  I could have earned a "disciplined" badge.  ;)

Comment: OK, i'm going to go ahead and accept this; i'm not sure if i'll end up using it since it is fairly complicated and hard to get right, but if i can get it to work, it would be a great optimization for large queues.

Answer (score -1):

If Your queue has a **maximum capacity** and You **only manipulate its front or tail**, I would use a [Circular Array](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node24.html). The following image is from the linked site and illustrates the idea behind circular arrays:

[image: circular array]
<sub>(source: [ernet.in](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/img42.gif))</sub>

To quote:

> - Rear of the queue is somewhere clockwise from the front
> - To enqueue an element, we move rear one position clockwise and write the element in that position
> - To dequeue, we simply move front one position clockwise
> - Queue migrates in a clockwise direction as we enqueue and dequeue
>   emptiness and fullness to be checked carefully.

With this kind of data structure You obviously can't insert elements between two sequent elements already stored and You can't surpass a certain maximum capacity - I hope it suits Your needs.

Comment: =arge (huge, limited by address space, ie: effectivly unlimited) maximum capacity is kind of the point, otherwise i wouldnt be trying to optimize for space in the first place.

Comment: If you use a fixed-size circular array of size N, you will waste a huge amount of space when the queue is small.